# if ID=0, ignore in .WHERE lambda query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have 2 overloaded methods, since parameter SecondVar can sometime be available and sometimes not :-

```
private void DoSomething(int FirstVar)
{
    int SecondVar = 0;
    DoSomething(FirstVar, SecondVar);
}

private void DoSomething(int FirstVar, int SecondVar)
{
    DoSomething(FirstVar, SecondVar);

    if(SecondVar > 0)
    {
       var a = GetList().Where(x=>x.FirstId == FirstVar && x.SecondId == SecondVar);
    }
    else
    {
       var a = GetList().Where(x=>x.FirstId == FirstVar);
    }

}
```

Is it possible in the second Overloaded DoSomething to get rid of the If clause?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: which ID?  I have FirstID and SecondID

Comment: Are you familiar with default parameters?  You could collapse this into a single method with the signature: `private void DoSomething(int FirstVar, int SecondVar = 0)`.  Under the hood (*waayyy* under the hood) this would get compiled to (almost) exactly what you have here, but results in easier to maintain code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have an infinite loop here

```
private void DoSomething(int FirstVar, int SecondVar)
{
    DoSomething(FirstVar, SecondVar);
```

Apart from that, you can use a `Nullable<int>` as parameter, then you don't need an overload:

```
private void DoSomething(int firstVar, int? secondVar = null)
{
    var a = GetList().Where(x=> x.FirstId == firstVar &&
      (!secondVar.HasValue ||  x.SecondId == secondVar.Value));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This does not account for zero/ negative values supplied for `SecondVar`.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: What is wrong with zero or negative values for secondVar? OP has checked for `0` because it was his (incorrect) approach to check if the parameter is used at all. Incorrect because zero could also be passed as normal argument.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I got an error on secondVar:- Nullable object must have a value

Comment: @TimSchmelter the logic in the OP will only fire if `SecondVar` is positive, but a negative value or zero could be provided as an argument.  In your rewrite, you are not checking the value of `SecondVar`.  Your answer would give a different response than the OP's in the cases where `SecondVar` parameter provided was zero or negative.

Comment: @Johann: But not at the code i have posted. If you access `secondVar.Value` you must be sure that it exists. That's why i have checked for `secondVar.HasValue`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter for some reason its not working.  Before I was getting a list of 4 records but now, its not returning anything.  I like your approach a lot since I do not need to do an overload, however the where clause seems to not like the null

Comment: @Johann: It's difficult to help without sample data. Have you really used the code above? Maybe you have forgotten the negation operator or the parenthesis.

Comment: @TimSchmelter no everything is how you supplied the answer.  Correct negation and parenthesis

Comment: @TimSchmelter pasted the method I am working on with your changes

Comment: @Johann: No, you have not used the negation operator `!` from my code. This should work: `(!iAuthorId.HasValue || x.AuthorId == iAuthorId))`

Answer (score 6):

```
private void DoSomething(int FirstVar, int SecondVar)
{
    // DoSomething(FirstVar, SecondVar);
    var a = GetList().Where(x=>x.FirstId == FirstVar && (SecondVar == 0 || x.SecondId == SecondVar));    
}
```

Thanks for the edit - you're right - the op clearly says "When the second var is 0 then ignore".  So adding an optional nullable parameter was just way off base.

Comment: why wouldn't this create an infinite loop? Doesn't the function call itself over and over again on the first line?

Comment: Looks like this would work; this is not what OP asked for, though.  @JeremyK, there does need to be some logic around the self-reference.

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis in the end of the line but I am not allowed to edit it...

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as your "if"-statement, but written different (so maybe not what you´re looking for, but... :) ):

```
var a = SecondVar > 0
                        ? GetList().Where(x => x.FirstId == FirstVar && x.SecondId == SecondVar)
                        : GetList().Where(x => x.FirstId == FirstVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var a = GetList().Where(x => (SecondVar > 0 && x.FirstId == FirstVar && x.SecondId == SecondVar) || (SecondVar <= 0 && x.FirstId == FirstVar));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Nullable SecondVar` and `Coalescing operator` in the Where clause. In this case, if you don't pass `SecondVar`, it will be null and the query will not be filtered by SecondVar.

```
private void DoSomething(int FirstVar, int? SecondVar = null)
{
  var a = GetList()
          .Where(x=> x.FirstId == FirstVar && 
                     x.SecondId == (SecondVar?? x.SecondId));
}
```

If you need to filter by SecondVar if it is only positive then;

```
private void DoSomething(int FirstVar, int SecondVar)
{
  var a = GetList()
          .Where(x=> x.FirstId == FirstVar && 
                     x.SecondId == (SecondVar > 0? SecondVar: x.SecondId));
}
```

Comment: got an error :- Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

Comment: Sorry, brackets were missing, should be okay now.